# Using .split() function within for loop referencing own parameter

Tags: python, for-loop, split

I am attempting to split a given string input in the format:

`automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids`

and transform it into a list like so:

`[['automobile','car'],['manufacturer', 'maker'], ['children', 'kids']]`

The outer list basically should be separated by triple spaces, whereas the inner lists single spaces.

My code:

```
replacement_pairs = input().split('   ')
for p in replacement_pairs:
    p = p.split(' ')
print(replacement_pairs)
```

Returns this instead:

`['automobile car', 'manufacturer maker', 'children kids']`

Comment: you can use list comprehension instead `print([p.split(' ') for p in 'automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids'.split('   ')])`

Comment: ``p`` is just some name. Reassigning it just changes what ``p`` *will* point to, not what ``p`` *did* point to (the list element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension

```
data = 'automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids'

replacement_pairs = [group.split(' ') for group in data.split('   ')]

print(replacement_pairs)
```

result:

```
[['automobile', 'car'], ['manufacturer', 'maker'], ['children', 'kids']]
```

In your current code:

```
    p = p.split(' ')
```

is a no-op since, `p` just gets assigned to the next element in the next iteration. You can't do any assigning to it. A simple fix would be to use a accumulating list instead of the assignment:

```
replacement_pairs = input().split('   ')
result = []
for p in replacement_pairs:
    result.append(p.split(' '))
print(result)
```

Comment: I'll be using this, with a change in variable names. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobIvanov if it does your trick, consider accepting it.

Comment: @JLPeyret what do you mean by accepting it?

Comment: There are different ways to provide feedback to answers.  One is to upvote, one is to downvote.  When it is *your* question however, you can choose, *if it solves your problem*, to click on the checkbox you see next to the answer (right under the number of votes for that answer).  A lot of times, new users don't seem to be aware of that and to the person posting the answer it seems as if their work wasn't appreciated much.  Also, to other people coming later, an accepted answer shows that it did in fact solves someone's particular issue, so it is a workable solution.